# Displaying one line of text only in a table cell

Tags: css

I found several CSS solutions to display only one line of text in an element whose text content would otherwise occupy several lines. However they don't seem to work when the element is a table cell. Is it impossible to achieve such limitation in a table cell?

Comment: Have you tried white-space: nowrap; ?

Comment: Which solutions did you try, for which HTML & CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with using a combo of `max-width:` and `white-space: nowrap;` : [JS Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZQT6/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>content content and a bunch of other stuff.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
    max-width: 120px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but how to do if want to display an x number of lines rather then one line ??

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px; /* if you'd like the with set' */
}
```

This limits it to only using one line of text. If you also like to ignore br tags:

```
td br{
    line-height: 0px;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I also had more than one div inside of the cell. To help that I added td div{
    display: inline-block;
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use the property white-space: nowrap;

You can take a look here if you want more information

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp